# Async and Sync Functions Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, extract, synchronous

I have a couple of functions I am running to download a zip file from Nexus, then unzip/extract the contents of the zip file, finally a search for a specific file type.  All function work, however the synchronous search for some reason is not producing any results.  If I simply run the download and extract functions in 1 script, then execute the search in another script I get my expected results.  I am almost positive it is due to the search being synchronous whereas the download and extract are both async.  Is there a quick way to add the find function at the end after the download & extract functions have run?  Below is the code:

```html
    //npm modules
    const fs = require('fs-extra');
    const download = require('download');
    const unzipper = require('unzipper');
    const path = require('path');

    //Custom Variables
    const artifact = 'SOME_FILE.zip';
    const repo = "SOME NEXUS REPOSITORY";
    const url = "http://SOME URL/repository/";
    const directory = 'SOME DIRECTORY';

//Get Artifact and Extract it to local directory function
  const getArtifact = async () => {
    const getArtifact = await download(url+repo, "./unzip")
    const file = await fs.writeFileSync(directory+artifact, await download(url+repo))
     const readStream = await fs.createReadStream(directory + artifact).pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: 
directory}))
}

//Find function which should run after download and extract have been fulfilled

const findFile = function (dir, pattern) {
var results = [];
fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function (dirInner) {
    dirInner = path.resolve(dir, dirInner);
    var stat = fs.statSync(dirInner);
    console.log(stat)
    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        results = results.concat(findFile(dirInner, pattern));
    }
    if (stat.isFile() && dirInner.endsWith(pattern)) {
        results.push(dirInner);
    }
});
console.log(results)
return results;
};


//clear contents of directory before new download and extract
fs.emptyDirSync(directory)

//call download and extract function
getArtifact()
```

When I run "findFile" after the download & extract by itself in a separate script I get expected array output.  However, when I try to incorporate (see below) this into the same script I get the an empty array:

```html
    getArtifact().then(function findFile (dir, pattern) {
    var results = [];
    fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(function (dirInner) {
        dirInner = path.resolve(directory, dirInner);
        var stat = fs.statSync(dirInner);
        console.log(stat)
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            results = results.concat(findFile(dirInner, pattern))
            if (stat.isFile() && dirInner.endsWith(pattern)) {
                results.push(dirInner);
            }
        }
        console.log(results)
        return results;
        })
    })

    //Output

    []



    //If I try the following:
    getArtifact().then(findFile(directory, file))
    // I get same empty array
    []

    //If I run "findFile" in its own script after the download extract I get the following:
    [
    'SOME_FILE_PATH\\document1',
    'SOME_FILE_PATH\\document2',
    'SOME_FILE_PATH\\document3',
    'SOME_FILE_PATH\\document4',
    'SOME_FILE_PATH\\document5',
    'SOME_FILE_PATH\\document6',
    'SOME_FILE_PATH\\document7
    ]
```

Any help with how I can incorporate my findFile function into my existing download&extract function is appreciated...

Comment: What ide do you use to code? I copy pasted the first code block and most of the code was useless, you also used a variable getArtifact inside of getArtifact, you used await on sync methods, and assigned them variables you didn't use. Try fixing that code first and then edit your post

Comment: If you did a copy/paste, then i wouldn't expect them to work since the URL's where the artifacts are downloaded point to a local Nexus server which I took the address out of.  Also if you copy/pasted then the artifact, repo, and directory variables will not work either.....I use IntelliJ IDE......When all the variables are in place the first code block works perfectly....it is adding the Synchronous findFile function after the getArtifact() function.....

Comment: I didn't run the code, I just took a look at it, no matter what those variables values are the `getArtifact` function is still broken. Like i said, you first are assigning them variables that you don't use ever. Second you are using await on sync methods, you might be able to do that but it adds nothing and its useless.

Comment: So I am obviously not as technical as you are (or I wouldn't be asking newb questions on SO), but it works perfectly, i.e. reaches out to nexus and downloads an artifact, then it writes the artifact to the file system, then it unzips the artifact which is written to the file system.  It does this simply by calling the "getArtifact()" function.  It does all of it in order of the "const getArtifact", "const file", "const readStream"....

Comment: The question still remains, I have an async function and I need to execute a Sync Function after the Async Function executes.  Both Async and Sync function run (as stated originally) when executed independent of each other, i.e. execute "getArtifact" then execute "findFile".....Async function ("getArtifact") output provides the needed input for the Sync function ("findFile").

Comment: Yes It will work still, javascript is loose, but I'm just suggesting removing it because it's redundant and bad code. 
For getting closer to the solution I think you should make a variable content and set it  to `fs.readdirSync`, after that do the same foreach loop, in the callback function take the second parameter as index, and at the end of it add `if (content.length - 1 === index) console.log(results);` remove the other log after the loop. in `getArtifact` at the end of the function add `return new Promise((res) => res());`, this is just for debugging ofc